# Outgoing Email Office 365

Tags: office-365, central-administration, office, outgoing-email

I need to migrate, my actual smtp server, to smtp.office365.com
I have configured the SMTP at the domain (mydomain.xxx.xxx), and all goes good. Because the email can be sent when I create a test TXT file and drop it into PICK UP folder of the MailRoot.

In the "Outbound SMTP Server" of Central Administration, I enter (mydomain.xxx.xxx) There is no email sent after I set up the alert.
 I see the error "Cannot connect to SMTP host "mydomain.xxx.xxx"  in the Windows Event log.

I also tried to send and email from PowerShell cmdlet, but it fails.

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: is it 9smtp.office365.com) cloud based exchange server URL?

Comment: @Waqas Sarwaer MCSE I don't know, how could I find that info? Because I received that server from the administrators of my company..

Comment: did they give you the URL? check this http://rosebudtech.com/2013/01/01/how-to-set-up-an-smtp-relay-in-office-365/

Comment: I´m afraid that I have not access to login for the URL provided in resebudtech, https://login.microsoftonline.com, but  I can send emails from the TXT file in in C:\inetpub\mailroot\Pickup, do you know why?

Comment: Sorry, it is not an exchange server. It´s based on the cloud

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Your SMTP setting for server from IIS

IIS > select server > SMTP Email

[image: SMTP Email]

Enter your SMTP Server name,port 
and specify credential according your SMTP server

Comment: I did it. But I´m not sure if it´s correct, to use the same credentials to connect to office365, or I need to use, the credentials to connect to the server. Any case, I try with both. but I still receive False, from the power shell console.

Answer (score 0):

There are couples of things which you should confirm.

1. install the SMTP server locally according to [Office 365 settings](http://www.configureoffice365.com/configure-office-365-smtp-relay/)
2. You need SPO licensing for user " To setup your on-premise SharePoint server to use Exchange Online, you need to build SharePoint Online (SPO) accounts for those users and assign the appropriate SPO licenses." https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/158/t/59538

Also check this one https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/uspartner_ts2team/2014/02/11/replacing-an-exchange-smtp-relay-in-an-office-365-environment/

and this
http://rosebudtech.com/2013/01/01/how-to-set-up-an-smtp-relay-in-office-365/

Comment: The problem persists. I still receive the message from Event Viewer. Cannot connect to SMTP host " ".ID: 6857 IMHO I think that is a problem with my server, but I cannot find the error. I just have a question, why my smtp server works, when a put a TXT file in C:\inetpub\mailroot\Pickup, I received the email. But the connection with sharepoint is the problem. Thanks in advanced